# Close votes big raise

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, closed-questions

Usually (at least since I can see them) SO had about 10k close votes

After the new moderators election (2014) close votes count dropped a lot: about 2/3k

I was quite impressed and I accounted it on the new moderators that were working hard to clean SO.

Friday 7 march after my daily close votes review the count was 2.6K

Today I went to do my duty to review close votes and I was shocked to see that close votes raised to  29.1K

What has happened to SO during the weekend?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199879/fuzzy-the-number-of-questions-in-the-close-review-queue-a-dopamine-for-the-shut <-- this is what's going on

Comment: No, we limited the close queues to easier-to-close batches.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - for a given value of "easier-to-close".

Comment: @Oded: Yet we got it done. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters - yep. I have nothing but respect for the community taking the challenge to heart :)

Comment: I hope you are as excited as we were: http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1883809#1883809